# Optimizing the solution of the problem from O(n^2) to O(n) or lower time complexity

Tags: python-3.x

You are given two fractions: 0/1 and 1/2. In each step, you will get two adjacent fractions and you need to add them, if and only if, the denominator is equal to or smaller than the number obtained in that step and write it between those two adjacent fractions.

Example:

Step 1: 0/1,1/2

Step 2: 0/1,1/2

Step 3: 0/1,1/3,1/2 and so on

The add operator is defined as follows:

If (a/b) and (c/d) is added, then the sum is (a+c)/(b+d) which means that their numerators and denominators both are added to each other.

You have to find the kth fraction in the nth step.

Note: You will be given the values of n and k

Input format

First line: Two integers n and k (1

Output format

Print the answer in the format (int)/(int), like 3/5.

What i have done is just follow the problem statement and do accordingly. But this is increasing time complexity of the problem and it works fine upto n=600

**Here is a sample of the code that i have worked on**

```
from fractions import Fraction


n,k=map(int,input().strip().split())
arr=[(0,1),(1,2)]
length=0

for i in range(1,n+1):
    increment=0

    for j in range(2+length-1):

        if increment==0:

            nume=arr[j][0]+arr[j+1][0]
            denom=arr[j][1]+arr[j+1][1]
        else:
            nume=arr[j+increment][0]+arr[j+increment+1][0]
            denom=arr[j+increment][1]+arr[j+1+increment][1]

        if denom<=i:
            arr.insert(increment+j+1,(nume,denom))
            increment+=1
            length+=1

if k==1:
    ans="0/1"
    print(ans)
else:
    print (Fraction(arr[k-1][0],arr[k-1][1]))
```

Comment: Is this by any chance used for a problem on http://projecteuler.net?

Comment: i found this in codechef. Can you help me?

Comment: No, sorry. I don't know a better algorithm. Maybe people on https://math.stackexchange.com/ can help you